# Magento 2 | Add submenu to System->Configuration

Tags: magento2, submenu

I want to add a new submenu to this.
How can I do that and add more submenus to the new submenu?

Comment: I didn't understand your menu and submenu, for exemple `Mageplaza extensions` is a `tab` and inside this `Mageplaza extensions` are sections, so you want to add a new tab called `New menu` ?

Comment: Do you want new tab like Advanced, Services etc?

Comment: Do you want to add tabs like ADVANCED, GENERAL etc. or want to add sections under any tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="generalmen" translate="label" sortOrder="900">
            <label>New menu</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="generalmenu" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top admin-newmenu</class>
            <label>Section1</label>
            <tab>generalmen</tab>
            <resource>Vendor_Module::general_config</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>Group1</label>
                <field id="field1" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Field1</label>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

This will add :

[image]